# 1, == (1,) - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax, tuples

```
>>> 1, == (1,)
  File "<ipython-input-34-bddb0dd08d2c>", line 1
    1, == (1,)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why am I getting a `SyntaxError`? The line in the console points to the comparison operator '=='. I was trying to compare 2 tuples. Yes, `(1,) == (1,)` works.

Is this related to this ... ?

```
    1,

Out[1]: (1,)
,1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-2-d73977cd7b2e>", line 1, in <module>
1("")
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
def h():
print("hello from h")
h
Out[4]: <function __main__.h>
h()
hello from h
,h
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-6-89db5d24b531>", line 1, in <module>
h("")
TypeError: h() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
def h(""):
print("hello from h")
File "<ipython-input-7-e4606aaf3740>", line 1
def h(""):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
def h(a):
print("hello from h")
,h
hello from h
```

I am finding it funny - Python 3.6.3, doesn't happen on 2.7 or 3.5...

```
,ord A
Out[112]: 65
```

This is getting a bit ugly. Just tried new IDE - Pycharm with python 3.6.3. Console gives me syntax error on ",ord A" but Spyder 3.3.1 doesn't. Is this something to do with IPython? 7.2 gives same result on ",ord A" >> 65.

Ok, 5 Feb 2019. I seem to have fallen into a black hole. An IPython black hole. Seems Like I was getting confused by another sub language IPython which is what the console uses. %Autocall in IPython 'Make functions callable without having to type parentheses'.  Although setting %Autocall to 0 still seems to enable this behaviour.

Comment: you have a comma after the `int` 1 which is not valid python

Comment: formating caused ^ to seemingly point to first equals sign but console says last equals sign.

Comment: just change it to `1 == (1,)` which returns `False`, like I said you have an extra comma

Comment: @aws_apprentice I do not think this is what OP intends, rather the question is why syntax like in `a = 1,2` can not be used in this case.

Comment: does this help? `1, 1 == 1` >>> `(1, True)`

Comment: That's weird. @Chris_Rands  It produces a tuple but the first value is an integer.

Comment: Makes sense to me. `1, 1 == 1` is equivalent to `1, (1 == 1)`.

Comment: If I see 1,   then what do I see? Do I see an integer followed by a comma or a tuple?

Comment: @JoePythonKing: Chris's examplel produces a tuple with the results of two expression: `1` and `1 == 1`. The first one produces the integer object `1`, the second the boolean value `True`, so the final tuple is `(1, True)`. Equality testing (`==`) has a much lower operator precedence than a tuple display.

Comment: @JoePythonKing: If you see `1,` you see a `1` expression that is part of a tuple display, with only a single element. It is not an integer 'followed' by a tuple, it is an integer that is *part* of a tuple.

Answer (score 6):

It's invalid syntax. Python sees a tuple with 2 values created from the expressions `1` and `== (1,)`. The latter is an incomplete expression, so you get an error just for that part.

See the [*Operator precedence* table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), *tuple displays* have the highest precedence, so the expressions between commas are executed before creating the tuple object from the results.

So yes, you can create tuples with just commas, but then *each constituent part* has to be a complete expression. You can't create a tuple without using parentheses if you want the tuple to be part of a larger expression.

That's because for *any* expression that doesn't use parentheses but which does contain a comma, the comma will result in a tuple being created from the sub-expressions that lie before and after the comma (with the part coming after being optional). Use parentheses to change what Python sees as a complete expression. So if you want to compare two distinct tuples, you *must* use parentheses to deliniate both tuples, so use `(1,) == (1,)`. As soon as you drop either set of parentheses you are creating a single tuple containing larger expressions (e.g. `(1,) == 1,` creates a single-element tuple from the `(1,) == 1` equality test, resulting in `(False,)`).

Comment: 'Binding or tuple display'  I don't think I understand the operator precedence. Is the ',' (comma) an operator? If I put 1, in console it spits back (1,)  - so it assumes that is a tuple. -  (), = ()   in console gives me 'ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)'

Comment: `1,` is a tuple, yes. `(), = ()` is an [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), which attempts to assign a single value (the empty tuple `()`)` to a tuple of targets. That requires that the right-hand side is an iterable with 1 element in it, and that fails. That you can't assign to the empty tuple hasn't yet been determined. In assignment, the expression to the right of the rightmost `=` is always evaluated first, as per the statement documentation.

Comment: (1,) == 1, >>>
Out[87]: (False,)

Comment: @JoePythonKing: Yes, because that's `(1,) == 1` inside a 1-element tuple.

Comment: @JoePythonKing: again, the `,` is a *highest-precedence* operation. The expression before and after the comma (if there are any) are evaluated first, then the tuple is constructed from the results of those expressions.

Comment: ,1 >>> TypeError:  'int' object is not callable